# How do i show this :$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\cos kx+i\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sin kx $ is a geometric sequence with complex ratio?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I have tried to show that this:$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\cos kx+i\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sin kx $$ is a geometric sequence  with complex ratio but i don't succed , I have use transformation with Euler identity of cos and sin but no result , any help ?

**Note:** $i$ is unitary imaginary part

Comment: "Complex reason?" What do you mean by that?

Comment: Can you show the expression you get after using the Euler identity?

Comment: @SeanRoberson I'd assume they mean ratio instead of reason and it got lost in translation (the word for reason being ratio in some languages)

Comment: e^i\theta=cos theta+isin theta

Comment: So if you put the two sums together (because they run over the same range), you can use Euler's identity for each term in the sum. What do you get then?

Comment: sorry i write raison by french language , i meant ratio

Comment: for the first sum i have this :$1 + \cos(x) + \cos(2x) +\dots + \cos(nx) = Re(1 + z + z^2 +\dots + z^n) = Re\left (\dfrac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z} \right)$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Think of *De Moivre*'s formula

Comment: ah, good then the ratio is e^(ix)

Comment: Absolutely. $ $